# List View Fragment Won't Display

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to display a list in my main activity using a ListFragment. The list is populated by my custom ArrayAdapter that uses a custom object. I am having trouble getting this list to show in the app. When I debug, it doesn't show any errors but the app immediately crashes.

Here is my fragment

Edit: I have tried several responses and have narrowed down the issue to the momentObjectListView.setAdapter(momentObjectAdapter) in the ListViewFragment. I cannot find a reason why the momentObjectAdapter would be null so it must be momentObjectListView however I cannot find where the issue stems. Any help would be much appreciated. My activity_main.xml, fragment, main activity, and adapter code are all included.

```
public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    Activity myAct = getActivity();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    ListView momentObjectListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    //ListView momentObjectListView = getListView();

    MomentObjectAdapter momentObjectAdapter = new MomentObjectAdapter(myAct, R.layout.moment_object_list_item);

    //momentObjectListView.setAdapter(momentObjectAdapter);

    List<MomentObject> myMoments = getMoments();
    for(final MomentObject entry : myMoments) {
        momentObjectAdapter.add(entry);
    }

    //ListViewFragment.this.setListAdapter(momentObjectAdapter);
    momentObjectListView.setAdapter(momentObjectAdapter);

    return view;
}

private List<MomentObject> getMoments() {

    // Let's setup some test data.
    // Normally this would come from some asynchronous fetch into a data source
    // such as a sqlite database, or an HTTP request

    final List<MomentObject> entries = new ArrayList<MomentObject>();

    for(int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        entries.add(
                new MomentObject(
                        "Test Entry " + i,
                        "Anonymous Author",
                        new GregorianCalendar(2011, 11, i).getTime(),
                        R.drawable.photoicon
                )
        );
    }

    return entries;
}
```

}

And here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ffffffff">

<fragment android:name="com.malatras.moment2.ListViewFragment"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Please let me know if there is anything I need to provide to solve this.

LogCat:

```
    e02-24 18:54:29.119    2325-2325/com.malatras.moment2 I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-24 18:54:29.191    2325-2325/com.malatras.moment2 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-24 18:54:29.191    2325-2325/com.malatras.moment2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.malatras.moment2, PID: 2325
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.malatras.moment2/com.malatras.moment2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.malatras.moment2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.malatras.moment2.ListViewFragment.onCreateView(ListViewFragment.java:34)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.malatras.moment2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

MomentObjectAdapter:

```
    public final class MomentObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MomentObject> {

    private final int momentObjectLayoutResource;

    public MomentObjectAdapter(final Context context, final int momentObjectLayoutResource) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.momentObjectLayoutResource = momentObjectLayoutResource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        // We need to get the best view (re-used if possible) and then
        // retrieve its corresponding ViewHolder, which optimizes lookup efficiency
        final View view = getWorkingView(convertView);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = getViewHolder(view);
        final MomentObject entry = getItem(position);

        // Setting the title view is straightforward
        viewHolder.titleView.setText(entry.getTitle());

        // Setting the subTitle view requires a tiny bit of formatting
        final String formattedSubTitle = String.format("By %s on %s",
                entry.getAuthor(),
                DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(entry.getPostDate())
        );

        viewHolder.subTitleView.setText(formattedSubTitle);

        // Setting image view is also simple
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(entry.getIcon());

        return view;
    }

    private View getWorkingView(final View convertView) {
        // The workingView is basically just the convertView re-used if possible
        // or inflated new if not possible
        View workingView = null;

        if(null == convertView) {
            final Context context = getContext();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            workingView = inflater.inflate(momentObjectLayoutResource, null);
        } else {
            workingView = convertView;
        }

        return workingView;
    }

    private ViewHolder getViewHolder(final View workingView) {
        // The viewHolder allows us to avoid re-looking up view references
        // Since views are recycled, these references will never change
        final Object tag = workingView.getTag();
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;


        if(null == tag || !(tag instanceof ViewHolder)) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.titleView = (TextView) workingView.findViewById(R.id.moment_object_title);
            viewHolder.subTitleView = (TextView) workingView.findViewById(R.id.moment_object_subtitle);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) workingView.findViewById(R.id.moment_object_icon);

            workingView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) tag;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder allows us to avoid re-looking up view references
     * Since views are recycled, these references will never change
     */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView titleView;
        public TextView subTitleView;
        public ImageView imageView;
    }


}
```

moment_object_list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Layout for individual news entries in a list -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Icon shown next to the title/subtitle -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/moment_object_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="3dp" />

    <!-- Title of the news entry -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moment_object_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/moment_object_icon"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/moment_object_icon"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Subtitle contains author and date -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moment_object_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/moment_object_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/moment_object_title"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Need the Logcat messages, simply copy/paste, and make it look nice. I'll check.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Just added logcat messages, thanks.

Comment: Good, I posted an answer.

Comment: I think your list is not in the XML file that you are inflating but in `main_activity`

Comment: @jmalatras, Perhaps I know the problem you have, search  my answer on " object momentObjectListView is null". I hope you will move on with your project.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I meant to respond but I have had no luck with that either. I have stepped through and tried every input I can think about for the arguments into momentObjectListView and still have no success. I am really stuck here and just have no idea what to do

Comment: Post your updated file ListViewFragment.java. You should change the code of inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view.. to the correct R.layout, perhaps activity_main instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code I don't like and not compatible with your method getMoments is:

```
for(final MomentObject entry : getMoments()) {
        momentObjectAdapter.add(entry);
    }
```

For now try this for a quick sample fix:

```
List<MomentObject> myMoments = getMoments();
for(final MomentObject entry : myMoments) {
```

The reason is getMoments() in the for loop is evaluated dynamically. I think so even though you declared it with final.

In the log,

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

I believe object momentObjectListView is null. I could not find the UI in **fragment_list_view**.xml. It is however in **activity_main**.xml. Sample code :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
ListView momentObjectListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Sample layout element for a ListFragment in **activity_main**:

```
 <fragment android:name="com.malatras.moment2.ListViewFragment"
 android:id="@+id/list"
 ...>
```

A good webpage for explaining layouts is required for understanding the basics @ [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) .

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately.

Comment: Is there anything that I am specifically supposed to have in the fragment_list_view.xml ? It is being inflated in the code for the fragment but I don't have anything in it besides a blank FrameLayout since I am creating the list in the code itself.

Comment: In this answer, I suspect it's code at ListViewFragment.java, line 34. This is related to the momentObjectAdapter and MomentObject, which I just noticed MomentObject class is not posted.

Comment: jmalatras, I think at this point, you will have to debug this part of code. I could not replicate the posted code, and I keep reviewing code that I do not see. This part of code is suspect because it is more complicated than it needs to be and the log supports it.

Comment: I believe object momentObjectListView is null. It could not find the UI element. This could have been easily detected by stepping through code in debugger. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I update/add code to the inflater in ListViewFragment.java. Please just respond back in this answer instead of the other ones, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I had actually thought of that earlier and it didn't work, tried again for good measure and still didn't work. I updated the ListViewFragment in my original post. LogCat is still giving a NullPointer exception for the momentObjectListView.setAdapter(momentObjectAdapter)

Comment: jmalatras, Your code in ListViewFragment has changed and I think the activity_main.xml also. Basically the question is "where is the ListView element"? I believe it was in activity_main before. The idea is the layout xml must contain the UI element you want, ListView in your case. I'll update my answer to be explicit in this area.

Comment: Remember momentObjectListView is null after code "ListView momentObjectListView =...". It needs to be not null for you to make progress.

Comment: The fragment code has not changed and the activity_main.xml has not either. There is no ListView element defined in the fragment or activity xml files, it is created in the fragment code using the adapter. Using this method, I didn't think it was necessary to define the element in the xml as well? The NullPointerException is invoked where the setAdapter call has an argument of momentObjectAdapter so wouldn't it be the momentObjectAdapter that is null? I could be wrong here but if it is the momentObjectListView that is null I am not understanding why it is null.

Comment: I hate to say but...we are "spinning our wheels" now. The ListView UI must be in a layout (as said in my answer). I updated my answer at the most bottom for you to read/understand layouts in general (link provided). It mentions about ListView object but not in the XML. Note that you're calling findViewById(), that means the ID must be located somewhere. You're not creating the UI dynamically in code and that would be much harder. If we cannot past this point and momentObjectListView is still = null, then I would have to "give up" and quit. Good luck sincerely...

Comment: Whew! After a week of back and forth we finally got it. I really appreciate your help. I added the List View element to the fragment xml and it initially didn't work. I then changed the id from android:id="@+id/list_item" in your answer to android:id="@id/android:list" and momentObjectListView.setAdapter(momentObjectAdapter); in the fragment to setListAdapter(momentObjectAdapter); and it compiled successfully! If you want to just change the android id at the bottom part of this answer to what I just mentioned as being the correct modification, I will mark this as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, that's great! I learned something too, that is about ListFragment hosting ListView, and that you can extract it from a fragment in xml. But most of all, now you can progress and have fun with the rest of the app. Post more interesting issues. FYI, you may click on the left of my answer as "helpful" also.

Comment: @jmalatras, If you think this answer was helpful to you, you may click on the left of the answer (the up icon). And you also can do that with other posted answers, including mine about "Binary XML file line #9...". One reason I am doing this is because I want to increase my rep by a lot this year.

Comment: Unfortunately to vote up I need 15 reputation and am not at that level. Once I hit 15 I will com back to this and upvote them.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your XML file this line :  `android:id="@+id/list"`

to:

`android:id="@id/android:list`

and in `ListViewFragment` change this :  `ListView momentObjectListView =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list)`;

to this:

`ListView momentObjectListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Comment: Still gave the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In your Logcat file, it says

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
> inflating class fragment

This means an xml file is not proper. Also deeper in the log,

> The code MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
> null object reference at
> com.malatras.moment2.ListViewFragment.onCreateView(ListViewFragment.java:34)
> ...
>
> ListViewFragment.onCreateView(ListViewFragment.java:34)

Need to load file ListViewFragment.java too. In order to save time, perhaps post more files.

Comment: I posted the Custom Adapter as well as the MainActivity and moment_object_list_item . I don't think it would be the moment_object_list_item as I had it working as the main activity fine but couldn't do what I wanted with the list in that position, so I want it as a fragment now. I am thinking it is something with the use of getActivity() as the context argument. I could be wrong so please let me know what you are thinking.

Comment: The log file says XML file line 9. The only question to me is which xml file? Since you did not post all the relevant layouts and code, you will have to tell me.

Comment: If you think, it's the Activity, then you inspect it via debugger or code like this: Activity myAct = getActivity() , and see if it looks valid.

Comment: I posted everything that is relevant, is there something that I am missing that you need? If there's an error in the XML line 9 I would think it would be the activity_main file as line 9 corresponds to the beginning of the fragment. If there is a problem with the activity then wouldn't that in turn prevent the xml from drawing?

Comment: I think your intuition is correct. I noticed another earlier line in the log file blaming the problem on MainActivity. I'll check.

Comment: Thanks let me know what you find. I also noticed that there is a NullPointerException that points to that same getActivity argument mentioned earlier but I can't figure out what the issue is there.

Comment: I used your code using ListViewFragment.java. Using Android Studio, it never likes ListViewFragment extends ListFragment due to runtime error "cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment". You may want to extends from Fragment instead since your MainActivity extends from ListActivity. Hence you already have a ListView object.

Comment: Unfortunately I just noticed you did not post the full ListViewFragment.java since the log file says "ListViewFragment.java:34". This may be the root cause of the problem. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have posted the rest of the ListViewFragment class, however line 34 is within the code I already had posted and the rest of the class is just the method to create test data to feed into the objects in the list. I really appreciate you putting the time into helping me with this

Comment: I posted another answer due to what I saw in ListViewFragment.java.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible good code change is to modify ListViewFragment definition from:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment {
```

to:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {
```

The OnItemClickListener is optional.

The reason I say this is that MainActivity already hosts ListView object through ListActivity. Another reason, Android Studio wizard generates the "to" suggested code. And it sounds good to me.

Another way is to remove ListActivity from MainActivity to just Activity, with the same reason.

All these suggestions may be considered to be code style however.

Comment: No luck with either of these. Still getting the null object reference in the context parameter for the ArrayAdapter but I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: I am sorry it is not clear. This is more of coding style than a solution. I'll edit this answer.